# Data processing with adding columns dynamically in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

I have the following problem.
Lets say this is my CSV

```
id f1 f2 f3
1  4  5  5
1  3  1  0
1  7  4  4
1  4  3  1
1  1  4  6
2  2  6  0
..........
```

So, I have rows which can be grouped by id. 
I want to create a csv like below as an output.

```
f1 f2 f3 f1_n f2_n f3_n f1_n_n f2_n_n f3_n_n f1_t f2_t f3_t
4  5  5   3   1    0    7      4      4      1   4     6
```

So, I want to be able to chose the number of rows I will grab to convert into columns (always starting from the first row of an id). In this case I grabbed 3 rows. 
I will also then skip one or more rows (in this case only one skip) to take the final columns from the last row of the same id group. And for reasons, I want to use a data frame.

After struggling for a 3-4 hours. I found out a solution as given below.
But my solution is very slow. I have about 700,000 rows and may be around 70,000 groups of ids. The code above at model=3 takes almost an hour on my 4GB 4 Core Lenovo. I need to go to model = maybe 10 or 15. I am still novice in Python and I am sure there can be several changes that will make this fast. Can some one explain deeply how I can improve on the code.

Thanks a ton.

model : number of rows to grab

```
# train data frame from reading the csv
train = pd.read_csv(filename)

# Get groups of rows with same id
csv_by_id = train.groupby('id')

modelTarget = { 'f1_t','f2_t','f3_t'}

# modelFeatures is a list of features I am interested in the csv. 
    # The csv actually has hundreds
modelFeatures = { 'f1, 'f2' , 'f3' }

coreFeatures = list(modelFeatures) # cloning 


selectedFeatures = list(modelFeatures) # cloning

newFeatures = list(selectedFeatures) # cloning

finalFeatures = list(selectedFeatures) # cloning

# Now create the column list depending on the number of rows I will grab from
for x in range(2,model+1):
    newFeatures = [s + '_n' for s in newFeatures]
    finalFeatures = finalFeatures + newFeatures

# This is the final column list for my one row in the final data frame
selectedFeatures = finalFeatures + list(modelTarget) 

# Empty dataframe which I want to populate
model_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=selectedFeatures)

for id_group in csv_by_id:
    #id_group is a tuple with first element as the id itself and second one a dataframe with the rows of a group
    group_data = id_group[1] 

    #hmm - can this be better? I am picking up the rows which I need from first row on wards
    df = group_data[coreFeatures][0:model] 

    # initialize a list
    tmp = [] 

    # now keep adding the column values into the list
    for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
        tmp = tmp + list(row)


    # Wow, this one below surely should have something better. 
    # So i am picking up the feature column values from the last row of the group of rows for a particular id 
    targetValues = group_data[list({'f1','f2','f3'})][len(group_data.index)-1:len(group_data.index)].values 

    # Think this can be done easier too ? . Basically adding the values to the tmp list again
    tmp = tmp + list(targetValues.flatten()) 

    # coverting the list to a dict.
    tmpDict = dict(zip(selectedFeatures,tmp))  

    # then the dict to a dataframe.
    tmpDf = pd.DataFrame(tmpDict,index={1}) 

    # I just could not find a better way of adding a dict or list directly into a dataframe. 
    # And I went through lots and lots of blogs on this topic, including some in StackOverflow.

    # finally I add the frame to my main frame
    model_data = model_data.append(tmpDf) 

# and write it
model_data.to_csv(wd+'model_data' + str(model) + '.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) is your friend.

This will scale very well; only a small constant in the number of features. It will be roughly O(number of groups)

```
In [28]: features = ['f1','f2','f3']
```

Create some test data, group sizes are 7-12, 70k groups

```
In [29]: def create_df(i):
   ....:     l = np.random.randint(7,12)
   ....:     df = DataFrame(dict([ (f,np.arange(l)) for f in features ]))
   ....:     df['A'] = i
   ....:     return df
   ....: 

In [30]: df = concat([ create_df(i) for i in xrange(70000) ])

In [39]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 629885 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
f1    629885 non-null int64
f2    629885 non-null int64
f3    629885 non-null int64
A     629885 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(4)
```

Create a frame where you select the first 3 rows and the final row from each group (note that this WILL handle groups of size < 4, however your final row may overlap another, you may wish to do a `groupby.filter` to remedy this)

```
In [31]: groups = concat([df.groupby('A').head(3),df.groupby('A').tail(1)]).sort_index()

# This step is necesary in pandas < master/0.14 as the returned fields 
# will include the grouping field (the A), (is a bug/API issue)
In [33]: groups = groups[features]

In [34]: groups.head(20)
Out[34]: 
     f1  f2  f3
A              
0 0   0   0   0
  1   1   1   1
  2   2   2   2
  7   7   7   7
1 0   0   0   0
  1   1   1   1
  2   2   2   2
  9   9   9   9
2 0   0   0   0
  1   1   1   1
  2   2   2   2
  8   8   8   8
3 0   0   0   0
  1   1   1   1
  2   2   2   2
  8   8   8   8
4 0   0   0   0
  1   1   1   1
  2   2   2   2
  9   9   9   9

[20 rows x 3 columns]

In [38]: groups.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 280000 entries, (0, 0) to (69999, 9)
Data columns (total 3 columns):
f1    280000 non-null int64
f2    280000 non-null int64
f3    280000 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(3)
```

And pretty fast

```
In [32]: %timeit concat([df.groupby('A').head(3),df.groupby('A').tail(1)]).sort_index()
1 loops, best of 3: 1.16 s per loop
```

For further manipulation you usually should stop here and use this (as its in a nice grouped format that's easy to deal with).

If you want to translate this to a wide format

```
In [35]: dfg = groups.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: Series(x.values.ravel()))

In [36]: %timeit groups.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: Series(x.values.ravel()))
dfg.head()
groups.info()
1 loops, best of 3: 14.5 s per loop
In [40]: dfg.columns = [ "{0}_{1}".format(f,i) for i in range(1,5) for f in features ]

In [41]: dfg.head()
Out[41]: 
   f1_1  f2_1  f3_1  f1_2  f2_2  f3_2  f1_3  f2_3  f3_3  f1_4  f2_4  f3_4
A                                                                        
0     0     0     0     1     1     1     2     2     2     7     7     7
1     0     0     0     1     1     1     2     2     2     9     9     9
2     0     0     0     1     1     1     2     2     2     8     8     8
3     0     0     0     1     1     1     2     2     2     8     8     8
4     0     0     0     1     1     1     2     2     2     9     9     9

[5 rows x 12 columns]

In [42]: dfg.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 70000 entries, 0 to 69999
Data columns (total 12 columns):
f1_1    70000 non-null int64
f2_1    70000 non-null int64
f3_1    70000 non-null int64
f1_2    70000 non-null int64
f2_2    70000 non-null int64
f3_2    70000 non-null int64
f1_3    70000 non-null int64
f2_3    70000 non-null int64
f3_3    70000 non-null int64
f1_4    70000 non-null int64
f2_4    70000 non-null int64
f3_4    70000 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(12)
```

Comment: Wow! This is why I absolutely love stackoverflow. Jeff I will look into your answer slowly. And I will get back to you shortly. There is once mistake I made, I missed the first line in my code where I was actually getting csv_by_id using a groupby. I am adding/editing that line in my code.

Comment: Jeff that worked. It reduced my code to 6 lines. Thanks. These two lines     <code>dfg = groups.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.ravel()))</code> and 
    <code>dfg.columns = [ "{0}_{1}".format(f,i) for i in range(1,5) for f in coreFeatures ] </code>
were Killers. Python is an art.

Comment: gr8. the trick is to always vectorize avoiding loops at all costs and do work only once

Comment: Sure. I am getting it. Think Vectors. Thanks.